# write formatted ASCII file with some syntax

Tags: python, numpy, io

Given an integer array `k` of length `n` and a float array `x` of shape `(n, 3)`, I need to write an ASCII file in the format

```
point 0
  x 0.7940323010739374
  y 0.4198839470828236
  z 0.9634270285267836
end point
point 1
  x 0.41661689592015294
  y 0.5225472280833198
  z 0.08362247218608498
end point
...
```

I see two possibilities: Write every block separately (slow), and store the file as a string and write it at once (memory-intensive):

```py
import numpy as np

n = 100  # very large
k = np.arange(n)
x = np.random.rand(n, 3)

# slow
with open("out.dat", "w") as f:
    for k_, x_ in zip(k, x):
        f.write(
            "\n".join(
                [
                    f"point {k_}",
                    f"  x {x_[0]}",
                    f"  y {x_[1]}",
                    f"  z {x_[2]}",
                    f"end point",
                ]
            )
            + "\n"
        )


# memory-intensive
out = "\n".join(
    "\n".join(
        [
            f"point {k_}",
            f"  x {x_[0]}",
            f"  y {x_[1]}",
            f"  z {x_[2]}",
            f"end point",
        ]
    )
    for k_, x_ in zip(k, x)
)
with open("out.dat", "w") as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Is there a better way to write the data? (Perhaps with a structured array?)

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Code Review is the right place, but just as note, you can get rid of the `join` by just using one string with all the fields and newlines in between. It is probably not much faster. If you care about run-time, you should do some profiling to find your bottleneck.